# OneDrive Android SDK upload error

Tags: android, onedrive

I am trying to upload to One Drive using the Live SDK for Android and I am getting "null" as exception every time.

Here is my code :

```
public void createFile(){
        Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable()
        {
            @Override
            public void run()
            {

                String fileName = "UploadTest.txt";
                String filePath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString() + File.separator + fileName;
                File file = new File(filePth);
                try {
                    final FileInputStream is = new FileInputStream(file);
                    client.uploadAsync("me/skydrive",file.getName(), is, new LiveUploadOperationListener() {
                        public void onUploadFailed(LiveOperationException exception, LiveOperation operation) {

                            Log.e("OneDrive","Error uploading file 1: " + exception.getMessage() );
                        }

                        public void onUploadCompleted(LiveOperation operation) {

                            Log.e("OneDrive","File uploaded.");
                            try {
                                is.close();
                            } catch (IOException ioe) {

                                Log.e("OneDrive","Error uploading file 2: " + ioe.getMessage());
                            }
                        }

                        public void onUploadProgress(int totalBytes, int bytesRemaining, LiveOperation operation) {

                        }
                    });
                } catch (IOException ioex) {

                    Log.e("OneDrive","Error uploading file 3: " + ioex.getMessage());
                    return;
                } catch (Exception ex) {

                    Log.e("OneDrive","Error uploading file 4: " + ex.getMessage());
                    return;
                }
            }
         });
        t.start();
}
```

Report from Log :

```
Error uploading file 4:null
```

I am trying to upload to the root directory.

Please help, thanks.

Comment: Find out which exception you are catching. The message is `null`, so print out the whole Exception (maybe call toString).

Comment: http://ideone.com/PE4U21 ... there is a big chance that you are getting NPE, so you got my downvote ... prolly `client` is `null`

Comment: @SelvinWell, thanks for the downvote.
I know its a NPE but i just couldn't find out which part is giving it.
Mostly the Path (me/skydrive), may be...but microsoft has mentioned it as the root path

Comment: `i just couldn't find out which part is giving it` then use debugger

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code works perfectly fine. There were some issues with Client instantiation and must be taken care of while instantiating.

Refer : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn631814.aspx